# C - default case not executed in a switch case

Tags: c

Consider this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum
{
    ONE=1,
    THREE=3,
    SEVEN=7,
    FORTYTHREE=43,
    SIXTYFOUR=64,
    ONEHUNDREDSEVEN=107,
    TWOHUNDREDTHIRTEEN=213,     
    ONEHUNDREDSIXTYSEVEN=167,
    THREEHUNDREDNINETEEN=319,
    FIVEHUNDRED=500,
    ONETHOUSAND=1000,
    NINENINENINENINE=9999,
    MAX_VAL,
};

int main() {
    
    int x = ONE;
    int y = 0;
    switch (x)
    {
        case ONETHOUSAND:
            y = x;
            break;
        case FIVEHUNDRED:
            y = x;
            break;
        case FORTYTHREE:
            y = x;
            break;
        case SIXTYFOUR:
            y = x;
            break;
        case ONEHUNDREDSEVEN:
            y = x;
            break;
        case TWOHUNDREDTHIRTEEN:
            y = x;
            break;
        case ONEHUNDREDSIXTYSEVEN:
            y = x;
            break;
        case THREEHUNDREDNINETEEN:
            y = x;
            break;
        default:
            printf( "Hit default %d\n", x ); //How is this not executed?
        case ONE:
            y = x;
            printf("HERE!!!!\n");
            break;
        case THREE:
            y = x;
            break;
        case SEVEN:
            y = x;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Executing this code gives the output `HERE!!!!` .
Why is the code under `default` not executed even though it is clearly falling through to the next `case` ?

From all I've seen mentioned, the order of cases or default doesn't matter, so why is this code behaving like this? I couldn't find any info about this behavior online.

Comment: `switch` doesn't work the way you think it works. There is no sequential top-to-bottom check of conditions. If `x` is `ONE`, execution goes directly to the `ONE` label. Execution goes to the `default` label *only* if the value of `x` is not among the labels.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI so fall through behavior only applies to case statements and not default ?

Comment: No, the fall through behaviour applies everywhere. In order to fall through, you need to go to the label above first, and you don't.

Comment: Ah ok. So how a switch case works is that execution jumps straight to the case that the switch matches, and if there are no matches it jumps to default. The fall through behavior happens only after the jump to the relevant label.
This cleared up the confusion for me.

Answer (score 1):

"Falling through" means that after the `case` condition has been met, the code directly after it has been executed and there is no `break`. It will then continue executing the `case` *below* it no matter if that condition is fulfilled or not. Generally "fall through" is recognized as bad and dangerous programming practice to avoid.

The `default` condition does not mean "any" condition, it means: anything *except* the other explicitly mentioned `case` conditions.

---

As a side note, the upcoming C23 standard provides an attribute `[[fallthrough]]` which can be used as self-documenting code to show that a fall-through was intentional, letting the compiler warn against everything else.

Answer (score 1):

As `n. m. could be an ai` said, the `default:` case doesn't execute until the compiler has not checked all conditions. What I mean is that even though you have put `default:` in the middle of all cases it doesn't mean it will execute after `case THREEHUNDREDNINETEEN` ; *it does not matter*.

---

If you want to execute `default` then obviously change `x` from `ONE` to something not in the switch (since default means "execute this if no other case satisfied").